Invalid write trying to allocate a 2D sheet of structures
My allocution of memory is incorrect and therefore i got a seg fault. I want to create a board game represented by a 2D sheet of cases (structures).
For the context, i'm coding a game of Tetris. The tetrominos are the pieces a player can place on the board game. A board game has special cases which make you win cards, that's why i use a 2D sheet of structures.
Struct of the board :
typedef struct str_board {
  int row;
  int col;
  box ** game_grid;
} *board;

Struct of a box :
typedef struct str_box {
  int special;
  tetromino t;
}box;

And I try to initialize it with the function :
void init_game_grid(board b) {
  int count = 8;
  b->game_grid = malloc(b->row_number * sizeof(box*);
  for(int i = 0; i<b->row_number; i++) {
    b->game_grid[i] = malloc(b->row_column * sizeof(box*);
    for(int j = 0; j<b->column_number; j++) {
      b->game_grid[i][j].t = NULL;
      int r = rand % 2;
      if(r == 1 && count> 0){
        count --;
        b->game_grid[i][j].spécial = 1;
      }
      else{

        b->game_grid[i][j].spécial = 0;

      }
    }
  }
}


I want that after the initialization, the board is empty and some cases are special ones.
I have several invalid write causing crashes ans i don't know what to change After testing several variation of how i do my mallocs.

It is probably easier to declare a fixed size board to start with. You can then fill in each cell as required. Something like: Box* board[8][8];.

Box board[8][8]

b->game_grid = malloc(b->row_number * sizeof(box*);

b, which is a pointer to a struct str_board which has no member named row_column. It has a row member, a col member, and a game_grid member. Secondly, you're missing the closing parenthesis.
Moving forward, this call to malloc():
b->game_grid[i] = malloc(b->row_column * sizeof(box*);

makes no sense. You ought to be allocating memory for boxes instead of box *s, and you're again missing the closing parenthesis. It should be:
b->game_grid[i] = malloc(b->row_column * sizeof (box));

Though struct str_board doesn't also have any member named row_column, and this should be col.
Furthermore, there's no identifier named rand in your code. I assume that you were trying to call the rand() function. So this should:
int r = rand % 2;

be changed to:
int r = rand() % 2;

Morever, the type box has no member named spécial. It has a member named special. Every instance of spécial should be changed to special in your code.

You still have the nonexistent row_number in the last line.

Yes, I believe that ought to be row, and not row_number, but I am unsure. :)

Now your last line is just reiterating what you said at the beginning.  I'm not sure what you're trying to say in the rest of the answer. The type of b->game_grid[0] is box*, not box.

@Barmar I've updated it.
